# Optimal control with state dependent action space

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I'm new to optimal control and exercising with some toy examples. However, I cannot easily solve systems where the feasible action space is a function of the current state.

Suppose we have the following system
$$
\max J = \int_0^T u(t) \ dt
$$
subject to
$$
x(0) = x_0,\\
\dot x(t) = f(u(t)),\\
u(t) \in \Omega(x(t)) := \begin{cases}
[0,1] &\mbox{if } x(t) < \theta,\\
{0} &\mbox{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$
where $f$ is some nice nonnegative increasing function. We can rewrite this to an optimal stopping problem that stops at time $\tau$, i.e., we add the terminal condition $x(\tau) = \theta$ and the state constraint $x(t) < \theta$ for $t < \tau$. Is this the way to go or is there a better way to solve such a system?

Comment: Depending on $f(u)$ you might be able to change the integration variable to $x$, so: 
$$
\max\, J = \int_{x_0}^\theta \frac{u(x)}{f(u(x))} dx
$$